# Using Pivot in SQL Query for Long to Wide Formatting

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy in Python 3 to query a sqlite database.  My initial query is:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT member, sku, quantity FROM table GROUP BY member, csvdatabase')
```

This works and gives me three columns; however, the problem is that I want to convert this from Long to Wide format.  I tried using pivot function, but my machine does not have the memory to handle this:

```
df_new = df.pivot(index = 'member', columns = 'sku', values = 'quantity')
```

Is there a way to make the SQL query do this?  I came across several examples where the pivot function is used or the `MAX(CASE WHEN Key...`, but the number of sku's is too large to type into a sql query